# Error. Docker container mongo-cnt doesn't start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Can someone help me? I have dockers files and project that has mongobd and back-end on node.js. I read a lot of articals but can't find any answers that solve this problem. The mongo-cnt container doesn’t start and show:

```
 Error message (] WiredTiger error (1) [1573219560:340726][1:0x7fc183f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1573219560:340726][1:0x7fc1
83f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted)
```

. Also, I must start this project on windows10.
I use for work docker-desktop(version 2.1.0.4).
Please, look at these 2 files and logs.

docker-compose.sh:

```
    retryOnErr() {
        until $1 2>&1 > /dev/null
        do
            echo "Try again ..."
            sleep 2
        done
    }

    docker-compose down  --remove-orphans --volumes

    rm -rf ./data

    docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build --renew-anon-volumes

    echo "Waiting for mongo bring up..."
    retryOnErr "docker exec -it mongo-cnt mongo --eval 'rs.status()'"
    echo "Mongo is UP ..."

    docker exec -it mongo-cnt mongo --eval 'rs.initiate({_id:"rs0", members:[{_id:0, host:"mongors:27017"}]});'

    docker-compose restart auditsvc
    docker-compose restart parsersvc
```

docker-compose.yml:

version: '3.7'

```
services:

  mongors:
    hostname: mongors
    image: mongors-img
    build: ./mongo-db/
    container_name: mongo-cnt
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      #- ./data:/data/db
      - mongodata:/data/db
      - ./mongo-db/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - ./mongo-db/mongo-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh
      - ./minuteMedia.postman_collection.json:/minuteMedia.postman_collection.json
    command: ["--config", "/etc/mongod.conf"]

  auditsvc:
    image: auditsvc-img 
    build: ./audit-service/
    container_name: auditsvc-cnt 
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 5858:5858
    depends_on:
      - mongors

  auditui:
    image: auditui-img
    build: ./audit-ui/
    container_name: auditui-cnt
    volumes:
    - ./audit-ui/nginx-react.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - mongors

  parsersvc:
    image: parser-img  
    build: ./parser/
    container_name: parser-cnt 
    volumes:
      - ./out:/app/out
    depends_on:
      - mongors
```

And logs:

```
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:25:59.807+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=478M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=t
rue,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.323+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1573219560:323308][1:0x7fc183f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1573219560:323308][1:0x7fc183f0fb00],
connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.325+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.162
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.326+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1573219560:326230][1:0x7fc183f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1573219560:326230][1:0x7fc1
83f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.337+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1573219560:337480][1:0x7fc183f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1573219560:337480][1:0x7fc183f0fb00],
connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.339+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.163
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.340+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1573219560:340726][1:0x7fc183f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1573219560:340726][1:0x7fc1
83f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.351+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1573219560:351210][1:0x7fc183f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1573219560:351210][1:0x7fc183f0fb00],
connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.353+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.164
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.354+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1573219560:354694][1:0x7fc183f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1573219560:354694][1:0x7fc1
83f0fb00], connection: __posix_open_file, 669: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.356+0000 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.356+0000 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 1: Operation not permitted
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.356+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 786
mongo-cnt    | 2019-11-08T13:26:00.356+0000 F  -        [initandlisten]
mongo-cnt    |
mongo-cnt    | ***aborting after fassert() failure
mongo-cnt    |
mongo-cnt    |
```

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: a very basic suggestion. have you cleared the volumes from previous run ? i.e delete all the files inside the volume mounts and restart the container ?

Comment: No, this project started first. Yep, after this error message, I tried to restart this container but the same error is shown.

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/74...seems to be related

Comment: Url that you shared for me isn't found.

Comment: seems related to this...https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/74